# Using WCHAR_T on AIX

Tags: c, character-encoding, aix, wchar-t

I have the following code on Linux:-

```
rc = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", SourceCode);
```

prior to calling `iconv` to convert the data into a wide character string (`wchar_t`).

I am now compiling this on AIX. The value `"WCHAR_T"` does not appear to work as the first parameter to `iconv_open`. It fails at runtime with errno=22 "cannot open convertor"

What should I change the above line of code to, in order for it to work on AIX.

Comment: `UTF-16BE` for 32-bit, `UTF-32BE` for 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you @LorinczyZsigmond - could you tell me how you came to know this information? Do you have a reference for example?

Comment: Well, according to the standard, `wchat_t` can be any integral type, and it can contain anything. So it's just experimental result.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond - can you describe your experiment and/or point me to the standard that you reference?

Comment: As a start, check definition of `wchar_t` in `/usr/include/ctype.h`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond- I think your advice to look in `ctype.h` may be answering a different question to what I am asking? I am wondering how you know that `"WCHAR_T"` is equivalent to `UTF-16BE` and `UTF-32BE` codepages. I am not wondering about the size of the `wchar_t` type.